# Convert RecursiveStruct1 to RecursiveStruct2 without recursion?

Tags: rust

```
pub struct Source {
    pub name: String,
    pub child: Vec<Source>
}
pub struct Target {
    pub id: String,
    pub nested: Vec<Target>
}
```

I can easily convert `Source` to `Target` using recursion, but it is not safe, because Source struct is a user-input data and it can cause stack overflow.

Are there simple ways to convert `Source` to `Target`  without recursion and cloning?  I've tried DFS but ended up with problems due to ownership.

Comment: Is it possible to validate it?

Comment: What means "validate"?

Comment: It's ok if Source is very deep nested, but it's not ok it it cause stack overflow if we are using recursion. Ofc, I can somehow limit recursion, but in this case it will produce a short version of Source

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for all recursive algorithm, you can do it iteratively by keeping a manual stack yourself:

```
impl From<Source> for Target {
    fn from (other: Source) -> Target {
        let mut stack = vec![];
        let mut t = Target {
            id: other.name,
            nested: vec![],
        };
        let mut it = other.child.into_iter();
        loop {
            if let Some (c) = it.next() {
                // "Recurse" to process children
                stack.push ((t, it));
                t = Target {
                    id: c.name,
                    nested: vec![],
                };
                it = c.child.into_iter();
            } else if let Some ((mut t1, it1)) = stack.pop() {
                // No more children, "return" from the current recursion level
                t1.nested.push (t);
                t = t1;
                it = it1;
            } else {
                // Stack is empty, we're done, return
                return t;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=699833ea4502d43c7bca68551fa55e4e)

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @Jmb is correct, but sometimes it is more convenient to use a recursive solution. In that case, you can grow the stack with [`stacker`](https://docs.rs/stacker/latest/stacker/) if the data is too big.